# Application restarts after pressing login button

Tags: android

I am trying to create a login script in Android. When I press the login button using the incorrect password, the app shuts down immediately. It is happening when I try to login using the wrong password. Find the code below:

```
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        String pass = txtpass.getText().toString();
        if( pass.equals("") ){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            StoreReport check = new StoreReport(Login.this);
            check.open();
            boolean ver;
            ver = check.verify( pass )? true : false ;
            if(ver == true) {
               //Starting a new Intent
               Intent logins = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DailyReport.class);
               startActivity(logins);
            } else {
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Password.. Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
          check.close();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I think your app is crashing. Share your logcat

Comment: How i can collect logcat from Samsung S2 phone ?

Comment: If you are developing on android studio,you can easily export log text on  a file.

Comment: You can use the command '<path\to\sdk\platform-tools\>adb logcat > log.txt' from the Command Prompt

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:418)
at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8603):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8603):  at com.syed.mubashshirhusain.personalreport.StoreReport.verify(StoreReport.java:81)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8603):  at com.syed.mubashshirhusain.personalreport.Login$1.onClick(Login.java:35)